# ansible grep plus awk with shell/command directive

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying run this ansible playbook

```
- name: Network Getting Started First Playbook Extended
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Disable wolverine
      shell: 'kubectl -n testns exec dashmpp-head-0 -c container -- bash -c "list versions | grep -w 20220928025228 | awk '{print $9}'"'
      register: target_db2_version
      failed_when: target_db2_version.stdout == "" or target_db2_version.stderr != ""
```

This keeps failing with:

```
      shell: 'kubectl -n testns exec dashmpp-head-0 -c container -- bash -c "list versions | grep -w 20220928025228 | awk '{print $9}'"'                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                            ^ here
```

Problem here is with `awk '{print $9}'` part. If I remove that the command works fine.

Here is what all I have tried already

1. Tried running the command manually on shell prompt and it works fine
2. `awk \'{print $9}\'`
3. `awk '{print \$9}'`
4. `awk \'\{print \$9\}\'`
5. Tries using `command` directive instead of `shell`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use two single quotes to denote a literal single quote within a single-quoted string in YAML:

```
      shell: 'kubectl -n testns exec dashmpp-head-0 -c container -- bash -c "list versions | grep -w 20220928025228 | awk ''{print $9}''"'
```

or in this case, there is no need to enclose the string in single quotes to begin with:

```
      shell: kubectl -n testns exec dashmpp-head-0 -c container -- bash -c "list versions | grep -w 20220928025228 | awk '{print $9}'"
```

Comment: I tried the both ways and printed the output. There is no syntax error but the awk does not work. Only the grep works. Here is the sample output

Comment: ```
TASK [Output register is_nlb_active] *************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "target_db2_version.stdout": "| 1 | 20220928025228 | 2022-09-28 02:52:28 |  v11.5.7.0  |    v1.22.08.03    | daily-20220926 |"
}
```

awk should print `v11.5.7.0`

Comment: OK I was able to fix this. I took awk out of the command. THank you.